# Estimating mean of a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X$ is a real valued random variable. Suppose $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mu$ is finite, and $\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \sigma$ is also finite. Now let $X_1, X_2,\dots,X_n$ be samples drawn from the same distribution as $X$. Define $\bar{X} := \frac{1}{n} \left( X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n \right)$. The question is how big is $|\bar{X} - \mu|$. In this case, of course, there is Chebushev's inequality that gives an upper bound.

Now assume that in addition that $\mathbb{E}(|X|^{1 + \delta})$ is finite for some $\delta \in (0,1)$, but $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ is not finite. Does anyone know if there is a replacement for the Chebyshev bound?

Comment: Using Markov/Chebyshev style inequalities, you get a bound involving $E(|\overline{X}-\mu|^{1+\delta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should look at is the Markov Inequality which require a finite first moment only
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#Statement

In your case, as $|\bar{X} - \mu|$ is nonnegative,
$$ \Pr\{|\bar{X} - \mu| \geq a\} \leq \frac {E[|\bar{X} - \mu|]} {a}  $$

Since the function $g(x) = x^{1 + \delta}$ is an increasing function, we can extend it to
$$ \Pr\{|\bar{X} - \mu| \geq a\} 
= \Pr\{|\bar{X} - \mu|^{1 + \delta} \geq a^{1 + \delta}\} \leq 
\frac {E[|\bar{X} - \mu|^{1+\delta}]} {a^{1+\delta}}$$

Comment: +1.  Note that this is Chebyshev's inequality when $\delta=1$